# Output of Ping Requests

Tags: ping

Suppose you send a ping request for an IP address: `ping 10.23.14.115`. What should the expected output be? Should you have something very short like:

```
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      
      Ping Statistics for 10.23.14.115
```

Or something long like:

```
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      Reply from 10.23.14.115, bytes -, ..
      
      
      Ping Statistics for 10.23.14.115
```

What happens if you get a longer result using one computer and a shorter result using another computer?

Comment: Try to increase cmd buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which system and which ping implementation you use.

On Windows, by default `ping` sends 4 packets only. So you get 4 responses, like the 1st example you give.  If you do `ping -t some-host`, it'll keep pinging until you stop it with `CTRL+C`.  You typically want to do this when you are restarting a server, you would do `ping -t your-server` so that you know as soon as the server is online.

On Linux, I believe by default `ping` keeps pinging the host until you stop it.